# No JSON object could be decoded - Django request.body

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7

I am making web service for posting comments from smart phone, Below is my code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def comment_post(request,newsId=None):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    responseData= dict({
       "result": list()
       })
    if(newsId):
        commentNews  = models.Comments.objects.create()
        commentNews.comment_description = data.get('comment_description').strip()
        commentNews.like_count = int(data.get('like_count'))
        commentNews.user_name = data.get('user_name').strip()
        commentNews.user_email_id = data.get('user_email_id').strip()
        commentNews.parent_comment = data.get('parent_comment').strip()
        commentNews.save()
        subscribed_user = models.SubscribedUsers.objects.create(username=data.get('user_name').strip(),email=data.get('user_email_id').strip())
        news = models.News.objects.get(id=int(newsId))
        news.comments.add(commentNews)
        data ={
         'status':'success'
         }
    else:
        data ={
        'status':'failure'
        }
    responseData['result'].append(data)
    return Response(responseData,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Whenever i check it on local it works, but on server side it gives me below error

```
ValueError at /service/comment_post/369

No JSON object could be decoded

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://dev.newskhabari.com/service/comment_post/369
Django Version:     1.9.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

No JSON object could be decoded

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode, line 383
Python Executable:  /var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/bin',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev',
 '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/newskhabari-app-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev',
 '/var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/app']

Server time:    Mon, 17 Oct 2016 11:35:36 +0530
```

I am unable to figure out why it give 
Exception Value: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: I think you don't have to do json.loads bcz in rest framework, you can access via request.data in a json format. Try that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess, You are using `django-rest-framework`. So, You don't have to do `json.loads()`, becasue `django-rest-framework` provides `request.data` for `POST` requests and `request.query_params` for `GET` requests, **already parsed in json format**.

So I think this should work for you.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def comment_post(request,newsId=None):
responseData= dict({
   "result": list()
   })
if(newsId):
    commentNews  = models.Comments.objects.create()
    commentNews.comment_description = request.data.get('comment_description').strip()
    commentNews.like_count = int(request.data.get('like_count'))
    commentNews.user_name = request.data.get('user_name').strip()
    commentNews.user_email_id = request.data.get('user_email_id').strip()
    commentNews.parent_comment = request.data.get('parent_comment').strip()
    commentNews.save()
    subscribed_user = models.SubscribedUsers.objects.create(username=request.data.get('user_name').strip(),email=request.data.get('user_email_id').strip())
    news = models.News.objects.get(id=int(newsId))
    news.comments.add(commentNews)
    data ={
     'status':'success'
     }
else:
    data ={
    'status':'failure'
    }
responseData['result'].append(data)
return Response(responseData,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

For further info read the the [docs here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)

Comment: It works for local but whenever i posted it on server it dont works.

Comment: It show below error
TypeError at /service/comment_post/369
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://dev.newskhabari.com/service/comment_post/369
Django Version:  1.9.5
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
Exception Location:  /var/www/vhosts/newskhabari.com/newskhabari_dev/app/mediapublisher/apps/mediapublisher/views/restViews/restViews.py in comment_post, line 167

Comment: in request.data it gives   {
     "comment_description":"yyyy",
     "like_count": "1",
     "user_name":"ooo",
     "user_email_id":"iiii@webmail.com",
     "parent_comment":"1"
   } as i posted for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125879/discussion-between-adil-malik-and-teekam).